# Bases for eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a d dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is in the span of $d<n$ eigenvectors. Then any vector in the subspace can be represented as a linear combination of the d eigenvectors. However, numerically, eigenvectors are generated with small errors and can be degenerate due to small errors. Then what are the other possible bases to represent any vector in the subspace?.

One option I know is Schur basis. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

All the vectors in that subspace are eigenvectors (except for $0$, of course) so any basis of the subspace will be a basis of eigenvectors. You don't have to use the basis consisting of the eigenvectors that happened to be the ones that determined the space for you. (Note that if those eigenvectors are numerically unstable then you may not even have the space you want.)